# React Native: Where exactly does it want the enclosing tags?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have what to me is a real messy return of a bunch of `View` and `Text` from `react-native` and I wanted to just remove the button that says ADD TO CALENDAR for now.

```
 const EventFeedCard = props => {


//prettier-ignore
  const source = props.event.ImageURL ? {uri: props.event.ImageURL} : defaultImage;
  //prettier-ignore
  const contentStyles = deviceHelpers.isTablet ? feedContentStyles.tabletContent : feedContentStyles.content;
  //prettier-ignore
  const contentFlexer = deviceHelpers.isTablet ? {flex: 2} : {flex: 1};
  //prettier-ignore
  const eventLocation = `${props.event.Location.City}, ${props.event.Location.StateAbbreviation}`;
  const displayTotal = props.isRegistered && !props.event.IsFree;

  return (
    <Card style={props.style}>
      <View style={feedContentStyles.header}>
        <Text style={feedContentStyles.title}>
          {`NFIB ${props.event.LegislatureType.toUpperCase()} EVENT`}
        </Text>
        <Text style={feedContentStyles.postDate}>
          {`On ${format(props.event.StartDate, "MMM D, YYYY")}`}
        </Text>
      </View>
      {!deviceHelpers.isTablet && (
        <View style={feedContentStyles.feedMainImageContainer}>
          <Image source={source} style={feedContentStyles.feedMainImage} />
        </View>
      )}
      <Divider />
      <View style={contentStyles}>
        {deviceHelpers.isTablet && (
          <View style={feedContentStyles.feedMainImageContainerTablet}>
            <Image source={source} style={feedContentStyles.feedMainImage} />
          </View>
        )}
        <View style={contentFlexer}>
          <Text style={feedContentStyles.contentTitle}>
            {props.event.Title}
          </Text>
          <View style={[styles.detailsRow, { marginBottom: 8 }]}>
            <Icon
              name="date-range"
              size={16}
              color="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
              style={styles.icon}
            />
            <EventDate event={props.event} />
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.detailsRow, { marginBottom: 8 }]}>
            <Icon
              name="location-on"
              size={16}
              color="rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
              style={styles.icon}
            />
            <Text style={styles.smallerText}>{eventLocation}</Text>
          </View>
          {displayTotal && (
            <View style={[styles.detailsRow, { marginBottom: 8 }]}>
              <Icon
                name="credit-card"
                size={16}
                color="rgba(0,0,0,0.54)"
                style={styles.icon}
              />
              <Text style={styles.smallerText}>{`$${props.grandTotal}`}</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <Text style={feedContentStyles.parragraph}>
            {props.event.ShortDescription}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      {props.isRegistered && <Divider style={styles.dividerPusher} />}
      <View style={[feedContentStyles.footerActions, styles.footerActions]}>
        // {props.isRegistered &&
          // (
          // <TouchableOpacity
          //   style={styles.calendarBtn}
          //   onPress={props.handleAddToCalendar}
          // >
          //   <Text style={styles.gothamBold14Black}>{"ADD TO CALENDAR"}</Text>
          // </TouchableOpacity>
        // )
      // }
        <TextButton
          color={v2Colors.green}
          title={"VIEW DETAILS"}
          titleColor={v2Colors.white}
          onPress={props.mainActionButtonPress}
          titleStyle={v2ButtonStyles.titleStyle}
        />
      </View>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

I understand that the `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag` means it needs to be wrapped in a parent div or fragment, but no matter what I try, I continue to get an error like so:

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: /Users/danale/Projects/NFIBEngage/src/events/components/EventFeedCard.js: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? (107:6)

  105 |           titleStyle={v2ButtonStyles.titleStyle}
  106 |         />
> 107 |       </View>
      |       ^
  108 |     </Card>
  109 |     </React.Fragment>
  110 |   );
```

I have wrapped either a div or fragment around the whole card, I have tried inside the card. Where do I need to wrap this parent div?

Comment: What does 'I am not resolving it' mean?

Comment: @MattWay, I clarified my statement. Thank you.

Comment: for the line `// {props.isRegistered &&`, you'd put comment `//` out for the js `{`

Comment: Can you please post the *exact* full return code that is producing the error.

Comment: @MattWay, posted the exact full return code.

Comment: Where you posted your error I see `React.Fragment` which isn't in your posted code! Also try cutting all your commented lines out, I don't think you can actually comment that way.

Comment: @MattWay, you want to see the code without the comments? Just to be clear, the error started after I began commenting. My intention is just to comment out the rendering of ADD TO CALENDAR, if that means I now have to add `<div>` or some parent element, fine, but where? It does not accept outside `Card`, inside it.

Comment: @MattWay, I figured it out, after you mentioned, we don't comment that way. Its inside `{}` so I needed to do `{/* */}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To comment JSX, it will need to be wrapped in curly braces:

```
        {/* props.isRegistered &&
          (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.calendarBtn}
            onPress={props.handleAddToCalendar}
          >
          <Text style={styles.gothamBold14Black}>{"ADD TO CALENDAR"}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      */}
```

Comment: Yep, after @MattWay mentioned it, I realized that I was commenting incorrectly. Thank you.